# Does jivatma have physical location?

Tags: atma, jiva

Does our jivatma have a physical location in space while it is incarnated in a physical body?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Yes Jivatma resides in the body and has the physical location, it resides in the cavity of heart.

> [Brahma-Sutra 1.2.11](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc62776.html)
>
> गुहां प्रविष्टावात्मानौ हि, तद्दर्शनात् ॥ ११ ॥
>
> guhāṃ praviṣṭāvātmānau hi, taddarśanāt || 11 ||
>
> guhāṃ—cavity (of the heart); praviṣṭau—the two that have entered;
> ātmānau—are the two selves (individual and Supreme); hi—indeed;
> taddarśanāt—because it is so seen.
>
> 11. The two that have entered into the cavity (of the heart) are indeed the individual self and the Supreme Self, because it is so
>     seen.
>
> In the Katha Upanishad there occurs the passage,
>
> “Having entered the cavity of the heart, the two enjoy the reward of
> their works, in the body” (1.3. 1).

Comment: does that mean if heart transplant happens, atma shifts to new body?

Comment: @mar No, no. Here cavity of heart doesn't mean cavity inside the heart, it means the cavity in which the heart is there. It is that place, where atma resides like Sukshma Shareera. Any change in Sthula Shareera won't directly affect it. It is just the location. Modern spiritualists say just like different chakras are associated with different glands, the heart center is associated with Thymus gland. The energy center there is probably where atma resides in the form of center of Sukhma shareera and Karana shareera. This is my understanding.